# Replace more options button in commandbar with an appbarbutton

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

how to replace more options button in commandbar with an appbarbutton(called button A ). I need to show other appbarbuttons with label(at bottom of Appbarbuttons ) ,when clicked on button A.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flyout in the AppBarButton

```
<AppBarButton Label="A">   
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="B"/>
                <Button Content="C"/>   
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>   
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```